# How to get alert when Ichange dropdown options using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my dropddown menu, when I change the option will get alert its working, but when i select again on the same option i didnt get alert.How it posiible

index.html

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div>
     <select ng-model="currentlySelected" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" ng-change="logResult()">
        </select>

        The value selected is {{ currentlySelected.value }}.
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    { label: 'one', value: 1 },
    { label: 'two', value: 2 }
    { label: 'three', value: 3 }
    { label: 'four', value: 4 }
    { label: 'five', value: 5 } 
  ];
  $scope.currentlySelected = $scope.options[1];

    $scope.logResult = function() {
     alert($scope.currentlySelected);   
    }
});
```

What I expect is if I select "two" twice i need to alert twice. Is this possible or should I be using a different directive for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. `onchange` event is fired when selection *changes*, not when you make a selection. So unless you choose different option, it's not going to fire.

If you need this behaviour I would suggest using one of the custom select solutions, even custom CSS based select would work. Then you could bind to onclick event instead of onchange.

Comment: I need that.when i click again on the same option want to show alert.Any idea

Comment: Well I posted what you need to do then: custom select. There are even very simple CSS solutions, then you would bind to ngClick and render options with ngRepeat. I would create a custom directive.